# CS50 PSet4 - Blur Filter, I am getting black image as an output

Tags: c, cs50

I'm writing the code for pset4, filter, blur of cs50. But my output image is black, or it simply doesn't give the correct output. I keep running into this problem.

What am I doing wrong in my blur function?

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    int sumRed;
    int sumGreen;
    int sumBlue;
    int counter;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < height; n++)
        {
            //Resetting sums to 0
            sumRed = 0;
            sumGreen = 0;
            sumBlue = 0;
            counter = 0;

            for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
            {

                if (x + i < 0 || x + i > width - 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++)
                {
                    if (y + n < 0 || y + n > height - 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    sumRed += temp[y + n][x + i].rgbtRed;
                    sumGreen += temp[y + n][x + i].rgbtGreen;
                    sumBlue += temp[y + n][x + i].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;

                }

            }

            temp[n][i].rgbtRed = round(sumRed / counter);
            temp[n][i].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / counter);
            temp[n][i].rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / counter);
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < height; l++)
        {
            image[l][k].rgbtRed = temp[k][l].rgbtRed;
            image[l][k].rgbtGreen = temp[k][l].rgbtGreen;
            image[l][k].rgbtBlue = temp[k][l].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to reverse `k` & `l` when accessing `temp` here: `image[l][k].rgbtRed = temp[k][l].rgbtRed;`

Comment: Doesn't your compiler shout some warnings at you? "Using `temp` without assigning a value" or similar? If not, turn up your warnings level. For GCC you can do this with `-Wall -Wextra`. While your question is probably already solved, you should do this for every program you compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real cause of black image is that `temp` is not initialized. To initialize it, we can simply copy the `image` into `temp`. Thanks @Gerhardh for pointing this out.

```
RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width]; // create a temporary array to store a duplicate of image.

// save a new copy of image as temp per color.
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) //Loop for height of image.
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) //Loop for width of image and save color values in temp.
    {
        temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
    }
}
```

There is another issue in your algorithm. You do calculation on `temp` and change `temp` at the same time which is wrong. Because as `temp` changes, new pixel blur calculations will be done on modified pixels. Calculations should be always done on raw image, then image should be assigned to temp values. A more detailed explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209966/cs50-blur-function-does-not-pass-check50-even-though-image-is-being-blurred/62210080#62210080.).

Basically, this piece of code,

```
temp[n][i].rgbtRed = round(sumRed / counter);
temp[n][i].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / counter);
temp[n][i].rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / counter);
```

should be this one,

```
image[n][i].rgbtRed = round(sumRed / counter);
image[n][i].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / counter);
image[n][i].rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / counter);
```

And remove this, since we already do assignment right after calculation.

```
for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < height; l++)
    {
        image[l][k].rgbtRed = temp[k][l].rgbtRed;
        image[l][k].rgbtGreen = temp[k][l].rgbtGreen;
        image[l][k].rgbtBlue = temp[k][l].rgbtBlue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing `temp` during calculation is wrong, but would not cause black pixels. Main problem is that `temp` is not initialized.

Comment: Thanks @Gerhardh. I modified the answer in the light of your comment.